# Can't get parameters from URL in angular io (5)

Tags: angular

The params is empty object.

I try to navigate directly to localhost:3000/bla?id=5,

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular, `router` is supported by `;` stead for `?` , So change your url like following:

**url**

```
 localhost:3000/bla;id=5;
```